# DateTimeIndex resample to create empty rows

Tags: python, pandas, series, datetimeindex

```
companies = users_file2.set_index('Created').Clean_Company2 
companies = companies.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='W')).unique() 
weekly = companies[:].apply(pd.Series).stack().drop_duplicates()
weekly = weekly.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
weekly = weekly.apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

I then performed `drop_duplicates` on `weekly` to get the following:

```
Created
2015-02-08    3
2015-02-15    1
2015-03-01    1
2015-06-21    8
2015-07-05    1
```

Now, I would like to fill in the missing weeks with 0. I have played around with `resample` and `reindex` but get some odd errors, for example, when doing the following:

```
df.resample('W').fillna(0)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

If I comment out `fillna(0)`, I get a `DatetimeIndexResampler` object, which I have checked by plotting, does not do what I want it to (not sure what it is doing, all values are binary when I do that, but it does fill in all the weeks)

The index is a `DateTimeIndex`, and the values are `int64`.

Comment: Can't reproduce this, this works fine on pandas 0.17.1, can you post your numpy, pandas version, and some code that reproduces the error

Comment: numpy: '1.10.4'
pandas: 18.0

Comment: You may want to edit your original post so that this is a bit more readable.

Comment: Done @mburke05, thank you